# Java Text Field of form to new form

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, label

I'm new in Java, just want to ask a simple question
I have my first form and a text field, I input a text there the once I click the button
a new form will come out and the Text in the text Field will be come a Label the the new form

I try this code but it doesn't work

```
public class Data extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  public Data() {
    initComponents();

    FrmLogIn f = new FrmLogIn();
    User.setText(f.UName.getText());
    User.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: have you included event listeners?

Comment: Swing?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I just need to get the text in the other form in the textbox

Comment: 1) Again, post an SSCCE.  That code would not compile.  2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) 3) *"doesn't work"* Is as useful in helping us to diagnose the problem as a screen door is on the ISS.  What did you expect to happen?  What happened instead?

Comment: for example.. Log In form
when I log-in
a new form will open and say, "Welcome, Username"

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you could tackle this problem.  You could create your own `JDialog` to handle the input requirements (and I probably would in most cases), but if you're after something a little simpler, `JOptionPane` provides a ready made dialog which is highly configurable.

[image][image][image]

There's, of course, nothing stopping you from mixing the two concpets (customized `JDialog` and `JOptionPane`)

```
public class TestLogin01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLogin01();
    }

    public TestLogin01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }


                LoginPane loginPane = new LoginPane();

                String userName = null;
                boolean validUser = false;
                int result = JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION;
                do {
                    result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, loginPane, "Login", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                    switch (result) {
                        case JOptionPane.OK_OPTION:
                            // Verify user details..
                            userName = loginPane.getUserName();
                            char[] password = loginPane.getPassword();

                            // Simple random test...
                            validUser = ((int) (Math.round(Math.random() * 1))) == 0 ? true : false;
                            if (!validUser) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inavlid username/password", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                } while (!validUser && result != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);

                if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                    if (validUser) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome back valued user " + userName, "Welcome", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class LoginPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField userName;
        private JPasswordField passwordField;

        public LoginPane() {
            userName = new JTextField(10);
            passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

            add(new JLabel("User name: "), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Password: "), gbc);

            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            add(userName, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(passwordField, gbc);
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName.getText();
        }

        public char[] getPassword() {
            return passwordField.getPassword();
        }
    }
}
```

You might like to have a read through [How to create GUIs with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [How to use dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

seeing your code, it seems that you have not included **event handling** part(and you need to include that to get your work done)

as an brief introduction you need to do this in your code:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                FrmLogIn f = new FrmLogIn();
                            User.setText(f.UName.getText());
                            f.setVisible(true);
                }
 }
```

**Note:** assuming `User` is an `JLabel` and `UName` an `JTextField`

and `FrmLogIn` has extended `JFrame` and you have set required fields like **layout and size** of the `JFrame`

for more info about event-handling look up [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

**Edit 2**:

sample code snippet - you want something like this ( its just a rough one to give you an idea how to move ahead wtih)

**edit 3**
as commented by @madProgrammer - replaced `null` layout by `FlowLayout`

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


class FrmLogIn extends JFrame{
    JLabel User;

    public FrmLogIn()  {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(200,200);
        User = new JLabel("");
       // User.setBounds(20,30,100,40);
        add(User);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}

class ForTest extends JFrame{
   JButton enter;
   JTextField UName;

    public ForTest()  {
     setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     setSize(300,300);

     enter = new JButton("enter");
     //enter.setBounds(20,20,100,30);
     UName = new JTextField();
     //UName.setBounds(40,80,60,30);
     add(UName);
     add(enter);
     setVisible(true);
     enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    FrmLogIn f = new FrmLogIn();
                                f.User.setText(UName.getText());
                                f.setVisible(true);
                                setVisible(false);
                    }
     }); 

     setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      new ForTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: for example "Log In Form"
when i log in my username, a new form will come open and says,
"Welcome Username," in the label i put

Comment: we got your point but its hard to predict what you have done and which part you want - check update

Comment: Yes, I use your code.. what happen is the log in form also came out..
but my jlabel in the welcome form still dont appear

Comment: @kelvzy wait a min? User is JLabel or JTextField?

Comment: @kelvzy and have you set the bounds of `JLabel` and added it to the Frame

Comment: User is jLabel in the 2nd form
and UName is my text field in the 1st form

Comment: so my UName = textfield is in the Login and my User= jLabel is in the Welcome form

Comment: woah thanks...
but I try this codes

String Namer = FrmLogIn.UName.getText();
       User.setText(Namer);

Comment: @kelvzy yeah thats your personal choice but you dont need to use `Namer` you can directly set it in setText

Comment: @MadProgrammer though layout was not the actual problem of OP so I left that as `null` now edited with `FlowLayout` - hope now you can - revoke your downvote

Comment: @sansix I'm sure I can be pursued ;) - Always good to present appropriate practices where we can (I know, I'm old and picky ;))

Comment: @MadProgrammer haha agreed :)